# не центрируется блок

Tags: html, css

У меня проблема не центрируется блок почти все пробовал не знаю теперь что делать
html

```css
.blk2 {
  text-align: center;
  /* пробовал align items center не помогло*/
}

#block {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 800px;
  background-color: rgb(100, 96, 96);
  border-radius: 20px;
}

#block h1 {
  color: white;
}

input[type="text"],
[type="date"] {
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  outline: none;
  background-color: rgb(80, 79, 79);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="u.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="blk2">
    <div id="block">
      <h1>Group</h1>
      <div class="onln">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Найти группу">
        <input type="date" placeholder="Год"></div>
      <div class="onln">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Предмет">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Учитель"></div>
      <div class="onln">
        <input type="text" placeholder="">
        <input type="text" placeholder=""></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: html body height

Comment: ? я вас не понел

Answer (score 0):

Вариант 1:

```css
.blk2 {
  text-align: center;
  display: block ruby;
}

#block {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 800px;
  background-color: rgb(100, 96, 96);
  border-radius: 20px;
}

#block h1 {
  color: white;
}

input[type="text"],
[type="date"] {
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  outline: none;
  background-color: rgb(80, 79, 79);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="u.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="blk2">
    <div id="block">
      <h1>Group</h1>
      <div class="onln">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Найти группу">
        <input type="date" placeholder="Год"></div>
      <div class="onln">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Предмет">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Учитель"></div>
      <div class="onln">
        <input type="text" placeholder="">
        <input type="text" placeholder=""></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Вариант 2:

```css
.blk2 {
  margin: 0 10% 0 10%;
  width: 80%;
}

#block {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: rgb(100, 96, 96);
  border-radius: 20px;
}

#block h1 {
  color: white;
}

input[type="text"],
[type="date"] {
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  outline: none;
  background-color: rgb(80, 79, 79);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="u.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="blk2">
    <div id="block">
      <h1>Group</h1>
      <div class="onln">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Найти группу">
        <input type="date" placeholder="Год"></div>
      <div class="onln">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Предмет">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Учитель"></div>
      <div class="onln">
        <input type="text" placeholder="">
        <input type="text" placeholder=""></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Предложу такой вариант. Для планшетов, компьютеров, ноутбуков вариант не так уж и плох, как может казаться на первый взгляд

```css
.blk2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}

#block {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 800px;
  background-color: rgb(100, 96, 96);
  border-radius: 20px;
}

#block h1 {
  color: white;
}

input[type="text"],
[type="date"] {
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  outline: none;
  background-color: rgb(80, 79, 79);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="u.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="blk2">
    <div id="block">
      <h1>Group</h1>
      <div class="onln">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Найти группу">
        <input type="date" placeholder="Год"></div>
      <div class="onln">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Предмет">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Учитель"></div>
      <div class="onln">
        <input type="text" placeholder="">
        <input type="text" placeholder=""></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: спасибо большое вы меня выручили

Comment: @Человек, рада была помочь)